# I have an ASP button for delete and its 'onclientclick' returns confirm to ensure deletion

Tags: asp.net, button, return, confirm

I have an ASP button for delete and its 'onclientclick' returns confirm to ensure deletion, but I do something in server and display another confirmation to ensure deletion again. How can I write the second confirm in the same handler of the button?

Answer (score 0):

use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) to add and script to page on run-time

Comment: Yes, but I need the script to be return confirm as I will do some thing according to the return value from confirm.The error is in the 'return' statement in the clientscriptmanager.